# What does 'how things are' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean ***the way the situation is***? Or does the phrase have a philosophical connotation?

> Mark Siderits’ ***How Things Are***: An Introduction to Buddhist
> Metaphysics (Oxford University Press, 2022) is a wide-ranging survey
> of how Buddhist philosophers think about the nature of the world. The
> book takes readers through topics such as the well-known claim that
> there is no self, in addition to issues involved in causation,
> consciousness, and the metaphysics of time. Siderits argues that, as
> mereological nihilists, Buddhists deny the existence of conventional
> persons as well as the more ontologically robust self. He shows how
> their sparse ontology makes use of causation as the central
> explanation for the wholes that ordinary people mistakenly take to
> exist. Throughout the book, Siderits makes connections between seminal
> analytic thinkers like Russell and Frege as well as more contemporary
> work in metaphysics. Written for philosophically-trained readers, the
> book emphasizes reconstruction of the arguments for important Buddhist
> metaphysical ideas, grounded in references to particular texts,
> thinkers, and traditions.

[How Things Are
An Introduction to Buddhist Metaphysics](https://newbooksnetwork.com/how-things-are)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As you suggest, it does mean "the way the situation is", or "considering the circumstances".

Random text example (from Google Books search): 2014, Lilia Amadio, *A Girl at War* (page 56): "No, we're all fine, **given how things are**. I get to see Alfredo in the evenings."

Answer (score -1):

I think it means 'accepting the things you cannot change'.  The acceptance of evil in the world, the acceptance that one individual is never in control, etc.  Yes, it can be philosophical. It could mean 'how things are' for them. Describing their perception of the world they live in, their beliefs and their lifestyle. These teachings are translated into English. North Americans, must remember that their teachings have origins in a different culture. Look for duplicity in their writings.

Comment: OP is asking what the phrase means, not what the book is about.